# Permission denied error when installing django

Tags: django

```
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/share/pyshared/Django-1.4.1.egg-info'

Storing complete log in /home/lightning/.pip/pip.log
lightning@rigel5:~$ 
OS: Ubuntu 12.10 32 bit 2GB RAM
```

Trying to install this via tutorial returns this error.

Comment: Which tutorial? What commands did you run?

Comment: https://www.djangoproject.com/download/

Comment: pip install Django==1.5 is the command I used

Comment: You need sudo to write to /usr/share

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: `sudo pip install Django==1.5`

Comment: ========
    WARNING!
    ========
    
    You have just installed Django over top of an existing
    installation, without removing it first. Because of this,
    your install may now include extraneous files from a
    previous version that have since been removed from
    Django. This is known to cause a variety of problems. You
    should manually remove the
    
    /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django
    
    directory and re-install Django.

Comment: so how do I manually remove that?

Comment: dont tell me: sudo uninstall Django==1.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django
sudo pip install Django==1.5
```

Comment: lightning@rigel5:~$ sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-package/django
lightning@rigel5:~$ sudo pip install Django==1.5
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Django==1.5 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Cleaning up...

Comment: I guess this worked.. would like to confirm before admitting victory on this one

Comment: >>> import django
>>> print(django.get_version())
1.5
its official. declaring victory. Eric, you da man. ty

Comment: I think it's properly installed. Make a test to verify if it works.

Comment: yup it was safely imported into the interpreter and returned the correct version. Thanks again Eric. Now, to glue my hair back in ;)